# My .bash_profile has started failing

Tags: bash, terminal

Major Edit: Upon more investigation I now believe that the problem is not in the .bash_profile but in something that runs after each command. I get a mysterious trace after each command -- even a new line. I don't know what to call this "something" and if someone could tell me I'd appreciate that.  Also, should I cancel this question and post a new one?

I originally posted on stackoverflow but it was suggested that I should have posted here so here it is:

I am using macOS 10.12.1

I use terminal and bash infrequently but something changed drastically about 6 weeks ago. Below is my .bash_profile which is unchanged for years and below that is the weird stuff that I now get when I open a terminal window.  I suppose that the problem is in my .bash_profile but it may be elsewhere.

I'm just not up to trouble shooting this and would much appreciate any help.

`.bash_profile`:

```
set -x
echo "Running ~/.bash_profile"

red=$(tput setaf 1)
none=$(tput sgr0)
PS1='\[$red\]***\t \! \w>\[$none\]'   # Using \W will provide just basename
#echo PS1=$PS1 
PS4=' $LINENO: '  # Set bash script prompt to line number of script
export PS4
alias cc="/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2"
DEV_INC=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include
#temp="/Developer/Tools:/Developer/Applications:"${PATH}:~/bin::
temp="/Developer/Tools:/Developer/Applications:"${PATH}:/Application s/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS:~/bin::
PATH=$temp
#echo PATH=$PATH
#include_path=.:/usr/include/:
#echo include_path=$include_path
echo BASH_VERSION=$BASH_VERSION

. ~/MYFUNCTIONS
export -f mygetopts isoption
compgen -A function  # List all functions
```

Trace of opening a new bash window:

```
Last login: Wed Nov 30 18:07:37 on ttys003
+ echo 'Running ~/.bash_profile'
Running ~/.bash_profile
++ tput setaf 1
cd ~/work
+ red=''
++ tput sgr0
+ none=''
+ PS1='\[$red\]***\t \! \w    \[$none\]'
+ PS4=' $LINENO: '
 10: export PS4
 11: alias cc=/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
 12: DEV_INC=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include
 14: temp=/Developer/Tools:/Developer/Applications:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/XXXXX/bin::
 15: PATH=/Developer/Tools:/Developer/Applications:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/XXXXX/bin::
 19: echo 'BASH_VERSION=3.2.57(1)-release'
BASH_VERSION=3.2.57(1)-release
 21: . /Users/XXXXX/MYFUNCTIONS
 22: export -f mygetopts isoption
 23: compgen -A function
isoption
mygetopts
shell_session_delete_expired
shell_session_history_allowed
shell_session_history_check
shell_session_history_enable
shell_session_save
shell_session_save_history
shell_session_update
update_terminal_cwd
  0: shell_session_history_check
  1: '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
  2: SHELL_SESSION_DID_HISTORY_CHECK=1
  3: shell_session_history_allowed
  2: '[' -n /Users/XXXXX/.bash_history ']'
  5: local allowed=0
  6: shopt -q histappend
  6: '[' -n '' ']'
  9: allowed=1
  11: '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
  12: return 0
  47: shell_session_history_enable
  1: umask 077
  1: touch /Users/XXXXX/.bash_sessions/AC4138F0-CE17-4189-80E4-29F987640EBB.historynew
  2: HISTFILE=/Users/XXXXX/.bash_sessions/AC4138F0-CE17-4189-80E4-29F987640EBB.historynew
  3: SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=1
  28: '[' 'shell_session_history_check; update_terminal_cwd' = shell_session_history_check ']'
  30: [[ shell_session_history_check; update_terminal_cwd =~ (.*)(; *shell_session_history_check *| *  shell_session_history_check *; *)(.*) ]]
  31: PROMPT_COMMAND=update_terminal_cwd
  0: update_terminal_cwd
  5: local url_path=
  9: local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=
  10: (( i = 0 ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=/
  12: [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=/
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=U
  12: [[ U =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=U
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=s
  12: [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=s
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=e
  12: [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=e
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=r
  12: [[ r =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=r
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=s
  12: [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=s
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=/
  12: [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=/
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=j
  12: [[ j =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=j
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=i
  12: [[ i =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=i
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=m
  12: [[ m =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=m
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=s
  12: [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=s
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=l
  12: [[ l =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=l
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=a
  12: [[ a =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=a
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=g
  12: [[ g =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=g
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=e
  12: [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=e
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  11: ch=r
  12: [[ r =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=r
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 16 ))
  23: printf '\e]7;%s\a' file://groksiMac-804.local/Users/XXXXX
***18:34:36 500 ~    cd ~/work
 1: cd /Users/XXXXX/work
  1: update_terminal_cwd
  5: local url_path=
  9: local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=
  10: (( i = 0 ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=/
  12: [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=/
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=U
  12: [[ U =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=U
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=s
  12: [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=s
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=e
  12: [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=e
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=r
  12: [[ r =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=r
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=s
  12: [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=s
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=/
  12: [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=/
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=j
  12: [[ j =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=j
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=i
  12: [[ i =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=i
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=m
  12: [[ m =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=m
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=s
  12: [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=s
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=l
  12: [[ l =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=l
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=a
  12: [[ a =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=a
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=g
  12: [[ g =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=g
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=e
  12: [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=e
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=r
  12: [[ r =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=r
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=/
  12: [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=/
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=w
  12: [[ w =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=w
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=o
  12: [[ o =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=o
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=r
  12: [[ r =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=r
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  11: ch=k
  12: [[ k =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
  13: url_path+=k
  19: (( ++i ))
  19: (( i < 21 ))
  23: printf '\e]7;%s\a' file://groksiMac-804.local/Users/XXXXX/work
***18:34:36 501 ~/work
```

Comment: How does this output differ from what you expect?

Comment: @Mark  I wouldn't expect to get all those lines of trace after a terminal window opens.  Clearly something is going on that shouldn't be.  I'm beginning to think that maybe the problem isn't in the .bash_profile but something that happens after it finishes.  Look in the trace and see those statements that begin with 'shell_session_'  Do you have any idea where they are coming from?

Comment: They're probably either commands in your `/Users/XXXXX/MYFUNCTIONS` file or the output of the `compgen -A function` statement in your `/Users/XXXXX/MYFUNCTIONS` file.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `set -x` from the top of your `~/.bash_profile`. `set -x` causes bash to output every command it runs before running it.  From the bash man page:

```
          -x      After expanding each simple command, for command, case command, select
                  command, or arithmetic for command, display the expanded value of PS4,
                  followed  by the command and its expanded arguments or associated word
                  list.
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  Please note the edit I just added to my question.  .bash_profile now seems innocent and something is running after each command and causing a long trace.  What runs after each command?

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation I have pinpointed the problem to the PS1 variable.  I have been using 
    PS1='[$red]***\t ! \w>[$none]' 
for years but it doesn't work anymore and causes a long trace on every bash command entered from the command line.  Commenting it out causes the trace to cease.